# How to decode HTML encoded character embedded in a json string

Tags: c#, json

I've a little question about decoding special characters from a JSon result (in my case,  \x27 but it could be any valid html encoded character). If the result doesn't contains any escaped characters, it works well but if not, I get a Unrecognized escape sequence exception. I try to do an HttpUtility.HtmlDecode on the Json string before deserializing using JavascriptSerializer, it doesn't work, the character still in encoded format.

Here's a code snippet:

```
public IEnumerable<QuoteInfo> ParseJson(string json)
{
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer jss = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<QuoteInfo> result = jss.Deserialize<List<QuoteInfo>>(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(json));
    return result;
}
```

I tried to use RegistersConverters to HtmlDecode any string I could find during deserialization but I can't figure out how to use it properly.

How can I solve that problem?

As back2dos nicely explained, this problem wasn't related to an HtmlDecode problem but to an misformatted Json string.

Comment: The string "\x27" is not a standard HTML character code, so the HtmlDecode function will not work on that.  Is that the format that you are seeing for the codes, or is that just the format you used in your example?

Comment: Yes, I see this kind of "encoded" characters in the string I receive. I know it's not standard Html code but when I do some quick testing like HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("Martin\x27s question"), it's decoded properly to "Martin's question" but it doesn't work for a complete JSon string ???

Comment: in response to your comment: google has ticketing systems for about anything ... you should really tell them ... as minor as this is, i am sure others will run into it ... greetz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, i have very superficial knowledge about `C#`, and none about the `.NET` API, but intuitively `HtmlDecode` should decode [***HTML* entities**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Html_entity#Character_references) (please excuse me if i'm wrong on that one) ... encoding is quite a b*tch, i know, so i will try to clearly explain the differences between what you have, what you tried, and what should work ...

the correct ***HTML* entity** would be `&#x27` and not `\x27` ... `\x27` is a hexadecimal ***ASCII* escape-sequence**, as accepted by some `JSON` decoders and many programming languages, but is **completely unrelated to *HTML*** ...

and also, it has nothing to do with `JSON`, which is the problem ... **[JSON specs for strings](http://www.json.org/string.gif) do not allow** hexadecimal ***ASCII* escape-sequences**, but **only *Unicode* escape-sequences**, which is why the escape sequence is unrecognized and which is why using `\u0027` instead should work ... now you could blindly replace `\x` with `\u00` (this should perfectly work on **valid** `JSON`, although some comments may get damaged in theory, but who cares ... :D)

but personally, if you have access to the source, you should modify it, to make it output **valid** `JSON` to match the specs ...

greetz

back2dos

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. No, I don't have access to the source of the code that output this JSon (I wish but I'm pretty sure Google won't let me change their code :). I'll try this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the requirements, but you could try looking at System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape (that's what I'm using, I'm guessing that there's an unescape but don't have time now to check the api, have to go to a meeting)

Good luck

Comment: Well, what I want to do it the opposite: I got a json string from a site with some escaped characters and I want to unescape them before passing the string to the JavaScriptSerializer class to deserialize the json string.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant, but I was under the incorrect assumption that there would be an unescape counterpart. There is not. Sorry :(

I am suprised that simply unescaping it doesn't work... what format are the escaped chars in:?

Comment: I guess that the reason HtmlDecode doesn't work it's because there's a lot of control characters in a json string (like " for example) and HtmlDecode doesn't handle this properly but I can be wrong. I've notice that if a pass only the problematic property to htmlDecode, it works but not with the complete string.