# How to decode a string like "string\x27s" in c#?

Tags: c#, string, decode, urldecode, string-decoding

I have a c# app that sometimes has to work with strings like:

```
"example\x27s string"
```

How do I decode that? I know 27 is the ascii code for a single quote `'`, but `UrlDecode()` wont work on that string.

Should I replace the \x value with % and then use `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode()` or is there another way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to decode HTML encoded character embedded in a json string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101532/how-to-decode-html-encoded-character-embedded-in-a-json-string)

Answer (score 1):

`\x27` is not an HTML encoded value. This is a string Escape character. The truth behind it though is that in the actual string is probably a physical `\` character so what you're dealing with is:

```
"\\x27"
```

Or

```
@"\x27"
```

I am unsure if .NET has a way to re-evaluate a string, but the \codes for strings are handled on a compiler level if i remember correctly.

You could use regular expressions to do a replacement if you want, since you know what it represents.